# How to extract university/school/college name from string in python using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
import re
line = "should we use regex more often, University of Pennsylvania. let me know at  321dsasdsa@dasdsa.com.lol"
match = re.search(r'/([A-Z][^\s,.]+[.]?\s[(]?)*(Hospital|University|Institute|Law School|School of|Academy)[^,\d]*(?=,|\d)/', line)
print(match.group(0))
```

I'm trying to extract University/School/Organization names from given string using regular expression in python but it gives an error message.

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Python/addOrganization.py", line 4, in 
>       print(match.group(0)) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: `print(match)` => `None`. It means that your regex is wrong for now. You should add `regex` tag to have more people help you.

Comment: @LêTưThành done adding the `regex` tag

Comment: Unless the strings are very simple, this is not a problem that can be solved by regular expressions.

Comment: As @BurhanKhalid said, this one only used for some very simple string. If you have interested in NLP, you can read more on Named-Entity Recognition.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It's just a demo string. the original string is much more complicated as compared to this one.

Comment: Please update the pastebin link in the question and update the line= "..." with an actual line from the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of search ,Try the re.sub to print your expected output

```
import re
i = "should we use regex more often, University of Pennsylvania. let me know at  321dsasdsa@dasdsa.com.lol"
line = re.sub(r"[\w\W]* ((Hospital|University|Centre|Law School|School|Academy|Department)[\w -]*)[\w\W]*$", r"\1", i)
print line
```

Comment: it's not a general expression working in this case only but not working in other cases like  `Pulmonary and critical care division, Washington university school of medicine, St Louis, Missouri 63110, USA`

Comment: @vinaynischal ,Give me some set of examples lines that contains the university or school names

Comment: Here is my pastebin link you can visit and check other examples of strings. https://pastebin.com/uYn7VS65

Comment: @vinaynischal,Its showing like "This page is no longer available. It has either expired, been removed by its creator, or removed by one of the Pastebin staff."

Comment: Check again. sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @vinaynischal,check now,Is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

The test string you've given is a made up one since the University name is immediately followed by a line terminator '.' while the other examples in your [pastebin sample](https://pastebin.com/uYn7VS65) do not (they are followed by a comma).

```
line = should we use regex more often, University of Pennsylvania. let me know at 321dsasdsa@dasdsa.com.lol
```

I have managed to extract the names using a simple regex for examples in your `pastebin` you can see details here: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/IxVeAw/1)

## Logic

**Since the institute name is separated by a comma (except the first case where it starts with the university name), you can see that the match string will either lie in `group1` or `group2`.**

Then you can iterate through `group1` & `group2`to see if it matches anything in the pre-defined match list & return the value.

## Code

I have used two examples to show it works.

```
line1 = 'The George Washington University, Washington, DC, USA.'
line2 = 'Department of Pathology, University of Oklahoma Health Sciences Center, Oklahoma City, USA. adekunle-adesina@ouhsc.edu'

matchlist = ['Hospital','University','Institute','School','School','Academy'] # define all keywords that you need look up
p = re.compile('^(.*?),\s+(.*?),(.*?)\.')   # regex pattern to match

# We use a list comprehension using 'any' function to check if any of the item in the matchlist can be found in either group1 or group2 of the pattern match results
line1match = [m.group(1) if any(x in m.group(1) for x in matchlist) else m.group(2) for m in re.finditer(p,line1)]
line2match = [m.group(1) if any(x in m.group(1) for x in matchlist) else m.group(2) for m in re.finditer(p,line2)]

print (line1match)
[Out]: ['The George Washington University']

print (line2match)
[Out]: ['University of Oklahoma Health Sciences Center']
```

Comment: The test string you've given is a made up one "should we use regex more often, University of Pennsylvania. let me know at  321dsasdsa@dasdsa.com.lol" 

In all other strings the line never ends with the university name, so this one doesn't match the regex you build for your other pastebin examples.